# Optimally splitting a text into strings from a set

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list, nlp, greedy

I am trying to write an algorithm that starts with a corpus of texts (e.g., a Wikipedia dump). It first builds an array of individual characters (e.g., `"a"`, `"b"`, `"7"`, `"0"`, `"."`, `" "`) and frequent substrings (e.g, `" the "`, `"ly "`, `" un"`, `"er"`, `"some"`). Then it splits up the text corpus into a sequence of those substrings.

I build the array as follows (not optimal but it's probably good enough):

```
from collections import defaultdict

corpus = [ ] # An array of strings, each string being a text
max_len = 5 # Longest sequence of characters to look for
strings = defaultdict(int)
for text in corpus:
    for n in range(max_len):
        for i in range(len(text)):
            if i+n < len(text):
                strings[text[i:i+n+1]] += 1

dict_size = 1000000 # Rough number of sequences to keep
min_count = sorted(strings.values(), reverse=True)[dict_size]
for key, count in strings.items():
    if count < min_count and len(key) > 1: # Keep frequent sequences and all individual chars
        del strings[key]
```

The part that seems trickiest is doing a good (or optimal) split of the texts. I assumed that longer substrings are less frequent and shorter substrings are less likely to collide, so my idea was to take a greedy approach: I run through the text sequentially once for each possible length in decreasing order. I use a linked list to keep track of the split out text:

```
class Token:
    def __init__(self, text, next=None):
        self._text = text
        self._next = next
        self._done = False

    @property
    def next(self):
        return self._next
    @next.setter
    def next(self, token):
        self._next = token

    @property
    def text(self):
        return self._text
    @text.setter
    def text(self, text):
        self._text = text

    @property
    def done(self):
        return self._done
    @done.setter
    def done(self, status):
        self._done = status

for text in corpus:
    head = Token(text) # Start the list with one token of the whole text
    for n in range(max_len, 0, -1): # Run through lengths in decreasing order
        token = head # Go back to the start for each run
        i = 0
        while True:
            if token.done or i+n > len(token.text): # If token is processed or end of token is reached
                if token.next:
                    token = token.next # Continue linked list
                    i = 0
                    continue
                else:
                    break
            if token.text[i:i+n] in strings:
                if i > 0: # Split out characters before match
                    token.next = Token(token.text[i:], token.next)
                    token.text = token.text[:i]
                    token = token.next
                token.done = True
                if len(token.text) > n: # Split out characters after match
                    token.next = Token(token.text[n:], token.next)
                    token.text = token.text[:n]
                    token = token.next
                    i = 0
            else:
                i += 1 # Run through characters in the token
```

This seems to work but I'm not sure how optimal it actually is, and I can't think of an algorithm that wouldn't run in exponential time. Initially I thought this may be a dynamic programming question but I don't think it works either because the character space is so sparse.

Comment: I feel like I am not really qualified to answer this, but I would like to point you to lexers / lexical analysis. They seem to be dealing with this exact problem and deal with it efficiently. For instance your browser uses a lexer to parse the wikipedia HTML. Sorry I cannot be more specific.

Comment: Might I suggest [CodeReviewStackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)? This question seem more suited there as optimization fall in their category.

Comment: Having read through it again: the second part (tokenization) is what a Lexer does. You can use a library to build the lexer, or employ FSM to build one. Sorry, I am quoting from memory of a great online course of Udacity: https://www.udacity.com/course/programming-languages--cs262

Comment: @RoyPrins If you know what strings you are grabbing, then a lexer will do it.  But the challenge is figuring out which strings to grab.